# Does "TextAreaFor" pass NULL to the model or empty string when its content is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Disclaimer Message", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.DisclaimerMessageText, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 3 })
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my model I have defined this:

```
public string DisclaimerMessageText { get; set; }
```

If I type something in the text area and save it, my model will have the value I typed and saves it successfully. But when I empty the text box and want to save, the value is NULL. I thought it would pass Empty String.  Is that normal behavior of how things work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. MVC normalizes empty strings as `null` on post. This is because there's effectively no way to post `null`, and it's more appropriate for a field that has not been set to anything to be `null` rather than an empty string. An empty string implies that the value was *intended* to be an empty string, which is usually not true.

If you want it to actually be persisted as an empty string, rather than `NULL` in the database, you can manually set the property to an empty string.